Which poster should I put up for promotion
If someone designs a poster promoting this site, I will put it up around uni in the Chinese language department.
Last year I did this myself, but I thought I might get some better designs if I opened it up.
School starts in march :)

I can do it but I have no ideas for now. I'm putting this as featured so other users can see it.

That's great. Hopefully a few people will put them up.
